# Как добавить на страницу панораму, используя модуль React?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

Файл проекта App.js выглядит так:

```
import { YMaps, Map, Panorama } from '@pbe/react-yandex-maps';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <YMaps>
         <Panorama defaultPoint={[55.786311, 37.723967]} />
      </YMaps>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Выдаётся ошибка

```
ERROR
[object Object]
    at handleError (http://***:3001/static/js/bundle.js:38783:58)
    at http://***:3001/static/js/bundle.js:38806:7
```